# Batch processing pandoc conversions

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, batch-processing, pandoc

I've searched high and low to try and work out how to batch process [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html).

How do I convert a folder and nested folders containing html files to markdown?

I'm using os x 10.6.8

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can apply any command across the files in a directory tree using `find`:

```
find . -name \*.md -type f -exec pandoc -o {}.txt {} \;
```

would run `pandoc` on all files with a `.md` suffix, creating a file with a `.md.txt` suffix.  (You will need a wrapper script if you want to get a `.txt` suffix without the `.md`, or do ugly things with subshell invocations.)  `{}` in any word from `-exec` to the terminating `\;` will be replaced by the filename.

Comment: many thanks. I assume I can replace `\*.md` and `.txt` with different extensions to convert the desired files. ie `\*.html` and `.md`?

Comment: Yes, that's why I detailed what was going on, so you could see more easily which parts to change to do what you need.

Comment: I don't quite understand the following: "`{}` in any word from `-exec` to the terminating `\;` will be replaced by the filename."

Comment: If you look at the sample command I provided, I used the character sequence `{}` twice:  once to specify the input file, and once the output (with `.txt` appended).  `find` replaces all instances of `{}` in an `-exec` command with the current filename.

Comment: Great answer. Just adapted this to batch convert .docx to .md with Markdown ATX headers and no line wrap: `find . -name \*.docx -type f -exec pandoc -o {}.md {} --wrap=none --atx-headers \;`

Answer (score 2):

I made a bash script that would not work recursively, perhaps you could adapt it to your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash    
newFileSuffix=md # we will make all files into .md

for file in $(ls ~/Sites/filesToMd );
do
  filename=${file%.html} # remove suffix
  newname=$filename.$newFileSuffix # make the new filename
#  echo "$newname" # uncomment this line to test for your directory, before you break things
   pandoc ~/Sites/filesToMd/$file -o $newname # perform pandoc operation on the file,
                                                     # --output to newname


done
# pandoc Catharsis.html -o test
```

Answer (score -1):

This builds upon the [answer by geekosaur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10323583/) to avoid the `.old.new` extension and use just `.new` instead. Note that it runs silently, displaying no progress.

```
find -type f -name '*.docx' -exec bash -c 'pandoc -f docx -t gfm "$1" -o "${1%.docx}".md' - '{}' \;
```

After the conversion, when you're ready to delete the original format:

```
find -type f -name '*.docx' -delete
```