# Converting all files in a folder to md using pandoc on Mac

Tags: makefile, pandoc

I am trying to convert an entire directory from html into markdown. The directory tree is quite tall, so there are files nested two and three levels down.

In answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023543/recursive-directory-parsing-with-pandoc), John MacFarlane suggested using the following `Makefile`:

```
TXTDIR=sources
HTMLS=$(wildcard *.html)
MDS=$(patsubst %.html,$(TXTDIR)/%.markdown, $(HTMLS))

.PHONY : all

all : $(MDS)

$(TXTDIR) :
    mkdir $(TXTDIR)

$(TXTDIR)/%.markdown : %.html $(TXTDIR)
    pandoc -f html -t markdown -s $< -o $@
```

Now, this doesn't seem to go inside subdirectories. Is there any easy way to modify this so that it will process the entire tree?

I don't need this to be in `make`. All I'm looking for is a way of getting a mirror of the initial directory where each `html` file is replaced by the output of running `pandoc` on that file.

(I suspect something along [these lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483182/recursive-wildcards-in-gnu-make) should help, but I'm far from confident that I won't break things if I try to go at it on my own. I'm illiterate when it comes to `GNU make`).)

Comment: If you don't know `make`, maybe you just try to write your own script in your favourite language, e.g. Python or Ruby? (sorry to not be of more help right now)

Comment: Yeah, I may just try that instead.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since you mentioned you don't mind **not** using `make`, you can try `bash`.

I modified the code from this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/43671), use in the parent directory:

```
find ./ -iname "*.md" -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc "${0}" -o "${0%.md}.pdf"' {} \;
```

It worked when I tested it, so it should work for you.

As per the request **Any ideas how to specify the output folder?** (Using `html` as the original file and `md` as the output):

```
find ./ -iname "*.html" -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc "${0}" -o "./output/$(basename ${0%.html}.md)"' {} \;
```

I have tested this and it works for me.

**Edit:** As per a comment, the `{} \;` when used with `find` and the `-exec` option is used as a, more or less, placeholder for where the filename should be. As in it expands the filenames found to be placed in the command. The `\;` ends the `-exec`. See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339015/what-does-mean-in-a-linux-command) for more explanation.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify. To get it to do what I want (viz. take `html` files and output `md` files) it should be: `find ./ -iname "*.html" -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc "${0}" -o "${0%.html}.md"' {} \;`, right? Any ideas how to specify the output folder? (As it is it just puts the `md` file in the same folder as the corresponding `html` one.

Comment: This results in the following error on my machine: `pandoc: : openFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)`. Files are found, but `${0}` appears to be empty.

Comment: What does the ` {} \;` at the end do?

Comment: Let me know if I should open a new question, but when I run this pandoc can't find any included files. For example, I have html and markdown files with images in subfolders (relative to the .md file). 

`<img src="Notes/Untitled.png"/>`
OR
`![Notes/Untitled.png](Notes/Untitled.png)`

Gives warning:
`Could not fetch resource 'Notes/Untitled.png': PandocResourceNotFound "Notes/Untitled.png"`

However, if I run pandoc directly on a markdown/html file it can find the image in the subfolder.

Comment: @SamTuke Make sure to have a folder `output` as the generated files are directed to it.

Comment: It may break if you have spaces in your filenames. To avoid it try ```for n in *; do
pandoc "$n" -o "./output/${n%.html}.md";
done```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it!

```
files=($(find ${INPUT_FOLDER} -type f -name '*.md'))
for item in ${files[*]}
do
  printf "   %s\n" $item
  install -d ${DIR}/build/$item
  pandoc $item -f markdown -t html -o ${DIR}/build/$item.html;
  rm -Rf ${DIR}/build/$item
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I've created a python script for converting all files under a folder tree which have a given suffix. It's called Pandoc-Folder. It might be useful, so I've put it on github: https://github.com/andrewrproper/pandoc-folder

You can create a settings folder and file (YAML format), and then run it like this:

```
python pandoc-folder.py ./path/to/book/.pandoc-folder/settings-file.yml
```

there is an example-book folder and matching .bat and .sh scripts for how to convert the markdown from the example-book folder into a single output file.

I hope this might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

John MacFarlane's answer is almost right. However, one needs to create the subfolder for pandoc, in case it doesn't exist. This is how I'd do it:

```
TXTDIR=sources
HTMLS=$(wildcard *.html)
MDS=$(patsubst %.html,$(TXTDIR)/%.markdown, $(HTMLS))

.PHONY : all

all : $(MDS)

$(TXTDIR)/%.markdown : %.html $(TXTDIR)
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    pandoc -f html -t markdown -s $< -o $@
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using ipython:

```
from pathlib import Path
files = [path for path in Path('.').rglob('*.html')]
for f in files:
    !pandoc -s {str(path)} -o {path.name.replace(".html",".md")}
```

Note that you must execute the command inside the directory where you keep the HTML files, and your file will be saved in the same directory. In case just change the output path.