# Convert all .docx in directory and subdirectories (recursive?) to .md using Pandoc bash

Tags: bash, pandoc

I want Pandoc to convert all .docx files in a directory to .md.

This directory has many sub-directories, and sub-sub directories, etc.

I want the output .md files to stay in the same directory (and sub-sub directory, etc.) as the .docx file from which it was converted.

I have tried many variants of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126362/converting-all-files-in-a-folder-to-md-using-pandoc-on-mac):

```
find ./ -iname "*.docx" -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc "${0}" -o "./output/$(basename ${0%.docx}.md)"' {} \;
```

I am aware that the "./output/" part of the command is specifying that the converted files be put in a directory called "output"

When I remove "./output/" from the command, the output .md files are all placed in the top-level directory from which the command is run. I want these output files to "stay" in the directory that their .docx file is in.

I am using Windows 8 with Cygwin. If the answer requires code (makefile?), I would like the language to be Lisp (obviously, I am not a programmer).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on: [Converting all files in a folder to md using pandoc on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126362/converting-all-files-in-a-folder-to-md-using-pandoc-on-mac?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I believe it should be:

```
find ./ -iname "*.docx" -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc "${0}" -o "${0%.docx}.md"' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wan to do it recursively keeping the directory structure :

```
target_dir="/path/containing/your/docx/files"
destination_dir="/output/path/for/your/md/files"

find "$target_dir" -type f -name '*.docx' -exec sh -c 'outdir="$2"; relpath="${3#$1/}"; mkdir -p "$outdir/$(dirname "$relpath")"; outname=$outdir/${relpath%.docx}.md; pandoc "$3" -o "$outname"  && echo "Converted $3 to $outname"' _ "$target_dir" "$destination_dir" {} \;
```