# How might I run Pandoc 'convert all files in Dir' command in Github Actions

Tags: docker, pandoc, github-actions

I would like to setup a github action that runs [this](https://pandoc.org/faqs.html#collapse-how-can-i-convert-a-whole-directory-of-files-from-markdown-to-rtf) command from pandoc FAQ on a repo when its pushed to master. Our objective is to convert all md files in our repo from md to another format using the pandoc docker container.

here is where I got so far. In the first example i do not declare an entrypoint and i get the error "/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec: line 11: for: not found."

```
name: Advanced Usage

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: convert md to rtf
        uses: docker://pandoc/latex:2.9
        with:
          args: |
            for f in *.md; do pandoc "$f" -s -o "${f%.md}.rtf"; done
```

In the second example we declare `entrypoint: /bin/sh` and the result is error "/bin/sh: can't open 'for': No such file or directory"

```
name: Advanced Usage

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: convert md to rtf
        uses: docker://pandoc/latex:2.9
        with:
          entrypoint: /bin/sh
          args: |
            for f in *.md; do pandoc "$f" -s -o "${f%.md}.rtf"; done
```

I am a total noob to git actions and not a technical person so my guess is this is easy idea for the SO community.  just trying some simple workflow automation. any explicit and beginner feedback is appreciated. thanks - allen

Comment: Worth noting, SO is the only reason I was able to get this far, if in fact I am on the right track at all!

Comment: maybe you need to quote it like `"for f in...."` and remove the "|" .... so that it becomes one argument? see https://github.com/pandoc/dockerfiles#github-actions

Comment: thanks @mb21, I tried that today and same message. my guess is that i am missing something more than just the syntax, or several somethings prob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to do a recursive conversion of md files to make a downloadable pack, so this answer extends beyond the OP's goal.

This github action will:

1. Make the output directory (`mkdir output`)
2. Recurse through the folders, create similarly named folders in an output directory (`for d in */; do mkdir output/$d; done`)
3. Find all md files recursively (`find ./ -iname '*.md' -type f`) and execute a pandoc command (`-exec sh -c 'pandoc ${0} -o output/${0%.md}.docx' {} \;`)

Note that you have to be careful with double and single quote marks when converting from stuff that works in terminal to things that get correctly transformed into a single docker command as part of the github action.

### First iteration

```
jobs:
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: convert md to docx
        uses: docker://pandoc/latex:2.9
        with:
          entrypoint: /bin/sh
          args: -c "mkdir output;for d in */; do mkdir output/$d; done;find ./ -iname '*.md' -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc ${0} -o output/${0%.md}.docx' {} \;"
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: output
          path: output
```

This solution was developed using @anemyte's info and this [SO post on recursive conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26126362/converting-all-files-in-a-folder-to-md-using-pandoc-on-mac)

### Second iteration from @caleb

```
name: Generate Word docs
on: push

jobs:
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    container:
      image: docker://pandoc/latex:2.9
      options: --entrypoint=sh
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: prepare output directories
        run: |
          for d in */; do
            mkdir -p output/$d
          done
      - name: convert md to docx
        run: |
          find ./ -iname '*.md' -type f -exec sh -c 'pandoc ${0} -o output/${0%.md}.docx' {} \;
      - uses: actions/upload-artifact@master
        with:
          name: output
          path: output
```

Comment: This is way better than if edited my answer with your solution. :)

Comment: There is another way to handle this as well setting the top level container to the Pandoc one so that any/all steps with simple `run: ` parameters get run inside the Pandoc docker container. See [my comments or your PR here](https://github.com/pandoc/pandoc-action-example/pull/11/files#r533657106).

Answer (score 1):

You can make your life easier if you do this with just shell:

```yaml
name: Advanced Usage

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  convert_via_pandoc:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    steps:
      - name: convert md to rtf
        run: |
          docker run -v $(pwd):/data -w /data pandoc/latex:2.9 sh -c 'for f in *.md; do pandoc "$f" -s -o "${f%.md}.rtf"; done'
```

The `-v` key mounts current working directory to `/data` inside the container. The `-w` key makes `/data` a working directory. Everything else you wrote yourself.

The problem you faced is that your `args` is been interpreted as a sequence of arguments. Docker accepts `entrypoint` and `cmd` (`args` in this case) arguments either as a string or as an array of strings. If it is a string it is parsed to create an array of elements. `for` became first element of that array and as the first element is an executable it tried to execute `for` but failed.

Unfortunately, it turned out that the action does not support an array of elements at this moment. Check @steph-locke's answer for a solution with correct `args` as a string for the action.

Comment: I couldn't get these to work on gh actions for me, but taking the info on the args etc, this did work: https://gist.github.com/stephlocke/7eafab0669b6568d423599b89eff9d43

Comment: Happy for you to incorporate the contents of the gist into your answer so I can award you the bounty :)

Comment: This gist modifies your args and entrypoints example - at least on my runthrough of getting this to work first, I found that gh didn't like an array of values for these

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I removed that part from the answer.