# space containing items in bash for-loop

Tags: bash, for-loop, whitespace, filenames, filepath

I want to recursively convert all markdown files under `./src/` to html:

```
#!/bin/bash

function do_recursive_pandoc {
local markdown_src_file_extension=\*.markdown
local markdown_src_path="$1"
local html_output_path="$2"
mkdir "$html_output_path" 2>/dev/null

for i in $(find $markdown_src_path -name $markdown_src_file_extension 2>/dev/null | cut --delimiter='/' --fields=2- )
do
    mkdir "$html_output_path"/$(dirname "$i") 2>/dev/null
    pandoc -rmarkdown -whtml "$markdown_src_path"/"$i" --output="$html_output_path"/"$i".html
done

}

do_recursive_pandoc "src" "output"
```

But if I have space in file paths or names bash will count them as multiple items in `for` loop, for example if I have:

```
./src/dir 1/foo.markdown
```

this script will make `./output/1` directory instead of making `./output/dir 1/` and tries converting `./src/dir` and `./src/1/foo.markdown` instead of `./src/dir 1/foo.markdown`

How I can fix that?

Comment: Use more quotes. Don't parse the output of `find`: use its `-exec` flag or use globs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive directory parsing with Pandoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023543/recursive-directory-parsing-with-pandoc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
#############################################################################
function do_recursive_pandoc {
    local src_path=$(realpath "$1") 
    local output_path=$(realpath "$2") && mkdir --parents "$output_path" 2>/dev/null
    find "$src_path" -name "*.markdown" -not -path "$output_path" -exec bash -c '
        i=$1
        o="$3""${1#$2}"
        mkdir --parents "$(dirname "$o")" 2>/dev/null
        if [ -f "$i" ]; then pandoc -rmarkdown -whtml "$i" --output="$o".html ; fi
        ' " " {} $src_path $output_path \;
}
#############################################################################
do_recursive_pandoc "src" "output"
#############################################################################
```

I pasted it along with a basic CSS  on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/5e58b6086f035ef85fdc).

Answer (score 1):

you would be better off piping find into while like this:

```
find $markdown_src_path -name $markdown_src_file_extension 2>/dev/null | cut --delimiter='/' --fields=2- | while read i; do
```

Comment: You should also use `read -r` in case there are other problematic characters in the file names.