# How to create a PDF Template?

Tags: flutter, pdf-generation

I'm trying to get my app to read a document (word or pdf) and generate a PDF from it, using variables to fill out certain parts.

I can't just let the user use a textinput as the ending PDF needs to respect Bolds, italics, identation, etc...

But I can't seem to find a way to do it.

Comment: Not that I really have hopes, but, still: did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that [Markdown](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet) is the most used solution.

You can insert whatever you want to the file, and then render it to PDF.

Comment: How would I read the markdown of a doc file and then generate a PDF with that?

Comment: There are different options for you. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383237/how-can-doc-docx-files-be-converted-to-markdown-or-structured-text) are shown some.

Comment: If you want to do it in flutter I would recommend to use a backend to convert the doc to a PDF using pandoc.

Comment: I can't afford a server. All I want is for ppl to submit a file stored on google docs for example, and to read it, change the variables and post a PDF

Comment: If you want to do it for a fixed amount of documents, use pandoc in the command line and make the entire thing as a commandline tool. If you want to create a service you can use an old pc as Server or search for an api, which converts doc to markdown. But I really recommend using markdown, since the alternative is very little and bad.

Comment: this app is used by a few hundred ppl and I have no idea what their documents are. just the variables.
I can't afford to have an old pc running