# Is there a way of importing (not linking) a Word doc into Azure DevOps wiki

Tags: azure-devops, wiki

I've got a Word doc with formatting that I want to be able to upload to a wiki in Azure DevOps without having to re-do all the formatting etc. Is there a tool/way of doing it?

tried copying/pasting but lose all formatting

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no. ADO Wiki is a git repo behind the scenes. So what you need to do is convert the doc to markdown and then copy the text to Wiki. Look at this thread: [How can doc/docx files be converted to markdown or structured text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383237/how-can-doc-docx-files-be-converted-to-markdown-or-structured-text)