# Batch convert files with pandoc in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, markdown, pandoc

I looked around and the only answer I found was pandoc (if anybody knows any programs with a ui that can do this in batches that would be great).

If not what I'd like to do is have two bat files in a directory, one to be able to convert all the files in a directory and any subdirectories from markdown to HTML, the other to convert back.

I just don't get how to get the "for in" recursive thing working in the command prompt (noob here). I got how to convert single files to and from with the examples from pandoc:

```
pandoc test.md -f markdown -t html -o test.html
```

or backwards:

```
pandoc test.html -f html -t markdown -o test.md
```

but I've yet to be able to do batches in either the command prompt or with a bat file. Googled it, got the few similar questions from here and I've tried to modify a few answers for me and still couldn't manage it.

If someone could give me the basic format it's supposed to be in, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Note that converting from HTML to Markdown will not work perfectly, as HTML is semantically richer than Markdown.

Comment: Try showing us a sample convert-from-html-to-markdown command and a convert-from-markdown-to-html command by editing them into your question. This shows us that you've done as you claim, the way that you've proved works for a file on your machine. Please also edit-out your call for other-product recommendations - it invites opinionated "language-wars"

Comment: I'm planning on only putting html I already converted back to md. I'm aware there's limitations, but it can indeed to it for what I need.

Comment: I added the back/forth code examples. I'm not sure what you mean by opinionated language wars. I literally found no other options but pandoc and this isn't about languages... *confused* I edited to specify I'm looking for something simpler with a ui that can batch convert because I had found nothing but pandoc which is a command line program as far as i understand. If you still want me to edit it out I can though, but I don't see how it would start any type of argument...

Comment: Also see here http://stackoverflow.com/q/17157638

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /s /a-d *.md *.html '
 ) DO (
 IF /i "%%~xa"==".md" (
  IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpna.html" ECHO pandoc "%%a" -f markdown -t html -o "%%~dpna.html"
 ) ELSE (
  IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpna.MD" ECHO pandoc "%%a" -f html -t markdown -o "%%~dpna.MD"
 )
)
popd
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

What this procedure would do is to simply `echo` the `pandoc` command to the screen. This is to allow you to see what would be executed before actually executing it. To actually execute the commands **after you're sure they're correct** simply change `echo pandoc` to `pandoc`

I've assumed that `pandoc` will deal with `"quoted filenames"` - which allows filenames to contain spaces.

As it stands, the code will execute the conversion only if there isn't already a "converted" file in existence with the same name part. If you want to convert regardless, remove the `if not exist...` before the `echo`. Downside would be that pandoc will convert `x.html` to `x.md` then reconvert the resultant `x.md` to `x.html`.

If you want to have two batches, simply duplicate the file and remove the `*.md` or `*.html` from the `dir...` line as appropriate.