# How can I convert specific web page to markdown or asciidoc with pandoc?

Tags: documentation, pandoc

I want to convert [java specification documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/index.html) to easily editable formats(markdown or asciidoc) and upload GitHub Gist and customize(adding my code experiences and notes.)
I want to convert to [something like this](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/7d9102373d60bd159920abfe96d636420afedd67/README.adoc#module-documentation,)

I use a tool called pandoc that allows us to convert from HTML to markdown.

I tried followings:

**Technique 1**
I tried to convert all table of components of java specification on index.html

```
pandoc -f html -t markdown -o test2.md  
https://docs.orac le.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/index.html`
```

I got this:[tes2.md](https://gist.github.com/lostdinar2/230753cdf5cbf42aa2c1fa349c92232d)
(I did not upload here because the file of contents is too long)

Problem 1:
This markdown file does not have contents of java specification documentation. I expected that I got markdown toc(table of components) and java specification documentation contents in markdown file like [this](https://github.com/AlanWalk/markdown-toc/blob/master/README.md)`

Problem 2:
When click the links on this markdown file then I get 404 error page.

**Technique 2(Better than technique 1)**
I downloaded all HTML files of TOC with HTTrack and try to convert all files separately.

```
pandoc -f html-native_divs-native_spans -i jls-1.html -t markdown -o test2.md
```

**Problem 1**:
I got following markdown file which have the table of components links that cannot redirect to another section of the same document. When I click on this links, they return external GitHub page like that:https://gist.github.com/lostdinar2/jls-1.html#jls-1.1
which is not available.
[test3.md](https://gist.github.com/lostdinar2/a1f5be5bd3fc411d6ea1a1e043719e60)

*A demonstration of **problem 1**:*

1)I want to convert this HTML internal id link(#) to the markdown internal link  that redirects to another section of the same document

```
<dt><span class="section"><a href="jls-2.html#jls-2.2">2.2. The Lexical Grammar</a></span></dt>

[link text](#abcd)
```

2)But pandoc cannot convert this links to the markdown internal link.Pandoc create an external link like this:https://gist.github.com/lostdinar2/jls-1.html#jls-1.1

Is there a pandoc parameter to fix this? I make a search on pandoc documentation but I cannot do this feature.

Comment: you'd have to write a script to download all the HTML pages you want. pandoc doesn't follow links.

Comment: Sure, I downloaded all HTML files, what can I do after downloading HTML files?

Comment: `cd folder` and `pandoc -f html-native_divs-native_spans -t markdown *.html -o output.md`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but I got following output: pandoc: *.html: openFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument) .Is there a way to fix this? Note that I am trying to execute this command in a directory which has 20 of HTML files.

Comment: the star only works on mac and linux. are you on windows? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27852067/batch-convert-files-with-pandoc-in-windows

Comment: yes, How can I do this on windows? And  `html-native_divs-native_spans` parameters cannot fix` technique 2-problem 1.I need to a pandoc parameter that converts HTML internal id link(#) to the markdown internal link.