# How can I use pandoc for all files in the folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, pandoc

In the FAQ on pandoc.org there is the instruction for Linux and Mac users:

```
for f in *.txt; do pandoc "$f" -s -o "${f%.txt}.rtf"; done
```

but there is no instruction for Windows users.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157638/batch-processing-pandoc-conversions-in-windows

Answer (score 3):

I was frustrated by this issue, so I wrote a batch file that you can run from cmd or from PowerShell that invokes pandoc on all the files of a specific type in a folder/directory, and in all subdirectories (i.e., it's recursive). The code is below. Copy the code into notepad and save it as `pancompile.bat`. It's easiest to run from cmd. From PowerShell you invoke it as `.\pancompile.bat`. If you run the command without any parameters, it will spit out sample usage like so:

```
Usage: pancompile DIRECTORY FILENAME [filemask] ["options"]
Uses pandoc to compile all documents in specified directory and subdirectories to a single output document

DIRECTORY         the directory/folder to parse recursively (passed to pandoc -s);
                  use quotation marks if there are spaces in the directory name
FILENAME          the output file (passed to pandoc -o); use quotation marks if spaces
filemask          an optional file mask/filter, e.g. *.md; leave blank for all files
"options"         optional list of pandoc commands (must be in quotation marks)

Minimal example: pancompile docs complete_book.docx
Typical example: pancompile "My Documents" "Complete Book.docx" *.md "-f markdown -t docx --standalone --toc"
```

And here is the code for `pancompile.bat`. Note that it will only work as expected if the total number of characters for all the directory paths and files is less than 8092:

```
@echo off
:: Check if user entered required options
if $%1$==$$ goto usage
if $%2$==$$ goto usage
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set "mask=%3"
if $%3$==$$ set "mask=*"
:: Remove quotation marks from pandoc options 
set options=%4
if not $%4$==$$ set options=%options:"=%
set "files="
:: This will only work if the total characters of all the paths and filenames together is less than 8192 characters
for /r %1 %%F in (%mask%) do call set files=%%files%% "%%F"
echo/
echo The following pandoc command will be executed:
echo/ 
echo pandoc -s %files% -o %2 %options%
echo/
:ask
echo Would you like to run pandoc on the files listed above? (Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=?: %=%
if /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
if /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto no
goto ask
:yes
pandoc -s %files% -o %2 --wrap=none %options%
echo Done
goto exit
:no
echo Command was cancelled
goto exit
:usage
echo/
if $%1$==$$ (
    echo This batch file needs to be run from the command line or from PowerShell
    echo/
) 
echo Usage: pancompile DIRECTORY FILENAME [filemask] ["options"]
echo Uses pandoc to compile all documents in specified directory and subdirectories to a single output document
echo/
echo DIRECTORY         the directory/folder to parse recursively (passed to pandoc -s);
echo                   use quotation marks if there are spaces in the directory name
echo FILENAME          the output file (passed to pandoc -o); use quotation marks if spaces
echo filemask          an optional file mask/filter, e.g. *.md; leave blank for all files 
echo "options"         optional list of pandoc commands (must be in quotation marks)
echo/
echo Minimal example: pancompile docs complete_book.docx
echo Typical example: pancompile "My Documents" "Complete Book.docx" *.md "-f markdown -t docx --standalone --toc"
:exit
:: End with a pause so user can read messages
echo/
echo Press any key to exit ...
pause>nul
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But the input files get sorted in a random order.

Comment: Try adding numbers to the filenames. Otherwise, you'd have to do some sorting on the files. Might be easier in PowerShell...

Comment: I tried adding numbers as prefix to filenames, but it does make any change.

Answer (score 1):

From [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pandoc-discuss/k4BKsq6fOVc):

```
for %F in (*.txt) do pandoc %F > %F~n.html
```

Comment: I tried to do it. But I can't open output files, in command prompt: `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Folder>pandoc input.html  1>output.html~n.docx`.  But if I use `pandoc output.docx input.html`, I can open the output file. But I don't know how to do this for many files

Comment: if you want do convert to docx you'd obviously have to replace `.html` with `.docx` in the line I posted...

Comment: Of course I did so `for %F in (*.html) do pandoc %F > %F~n.docx`. But it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I couldn't find a solution.

The problem is that in PowerShell you can't use wildcards like *.md. This simply is a Unix thing.

You will have to work with a single file in windows.