# Concatenate multiple Markdown files using Pandoc on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, cmd, markdown, pandoc

I have several Markdown (`.md`) files in a folder and I want to concatenate them and get a final Markdown file using Pandoc. I wrote a bash file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash 
pandoc *.md > final.md
```

But I am getting the following error when I double-click on it:

> pandoc: *.md: openBinaryFile: invalid argument (Invalid argument)

and the `final.md` file is empty.

If I try this:

```
pandoc file1.md file2.md .... final.md
```

I am getting the results I expect: a `final.md` file with the contents of all the other Markdown files.

On macOS it works fine. Why doesn't this work on Windows?

Comment: What does `ls *.md` in that directory give?

Comment: `ls *.md` gives back the 3 md files that i have for the testing. file1.md, file2.md and file3.md

Comment: And how are you running your script? It looks like your shell is failing to expand the file glob for some reason…

Comment: Ah. I guess you're on Windows? Are you using cmd.exe or PowerShell?

Comment: @Chris I just found the solution. Based on your comment, i tried and run  it via Cygwin like `bash run.sh` and the final file now has content. I do not know why, but if i try double click the file in current directory, i am getting file with no content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Unix-like shells (like bash, for which your script is written) glob expansion (e.g. turning `*.md` into `file1.md file2.md file3.md`) is [performed by the shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)#Implementations), not the application you're running. Your application sees the final list of files, not the wildcard.

However, glob expansion in `cmd.exe` is performed by the *application*:

> The [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows) command interpreter [cmd.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) relies on a runtime function in applications to perform globbing.

As a result, Pandoc is being passed a literal `*.md` when it expects to see a list of files like `file1.md file2.md file3.md`. It doesn't know how to expand the glob itself and tries to open a file whose name is `*.md`.

You should be able to run your bash script in a unix-like shell like Cygwin or [bash on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10). It may also work on PowerShell, though I don't have a machine handy to test. As a last resort you could [jump through some hoops](https://superuser.com/a/460609/312289) to write a batch file that expands the glob and passes file names to Pandoc.

Comment: This works with PowerShell: `pandoc (get-item *.md).FullName -o final.md`

Comment: I wrote a plain old batch file for Windows that will operate recursively on a directory and its subdirectories looking for files of a certain type and will then send them to pandoc. I call it `pancompile.bat`. The code is in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41471253/how-can-i-use-pandoc-for-all-files-in-the-folder-in-windows/52883778#52883778 . No doubt it could be rewritten much better in PowerShell, but it works for me.