# How to concatenate multiple markdown files in a specific order in Windows

Tags: windows, concatenation, pandoc

I can easily do this in LINUX using an includes.txt file:

```
pandoc -s $(cat includes.txt) -o index.html
```

where includes.txt contains:

```
file1.md
file3.md
file2.md
```

The problem is that I now have to do the equivalent in Windows and cannot figure out how to concatenate the Markdown files in the order specified in the includes.txt file and then pass this to Pandoc.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Concatenate multiple Markdown files using Pandoc on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49978926/concatenate-multiple-markdown-files-using-pandoc-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks, but that solution only appears to allow processing of 'all the files in a specified directory', and not the files in my 'includes.txt' file in the order they appear in that file (which is the important thing for me). My problem is just knowing how to translate my Linux command (which works just fine) into an equivalent Windows version.

Comment: Check my provided answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create a file `defaults.yaml` with the following content:

```yaml
input-files:
  - file1.md
  - file3.md
  - file2.md
```

Then call pandoc with `pandoc --defaults defaults.yaml …`.

Answer (score 1):

After a short research, I found that you can do the equivalent operation in Windows environment using Pandoc.

Download and install Pandoc using the following link. You should select `pandoc-2.9.2-windows-x86_64.msi`

[Pandoc](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.9.2)

After successful installation of Pandoc, open `powershell` to check if the program is successfully installed by running the following command.

`pandoc --version`

Now, running the provided command from your original post will work in Windows environment.

```
pandoc -s $(cat includes.txt) -o index.html
```

Comment: OK - thank you.
Your solution works with powershell, but not with cmd.exe (which is what I had been using).
When I try with cmd.exe, I get this error message: 
pandoc: $(cat: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)

Comment: Will powershell suffice or is cmd a mandatory? After another research with self tests, I can confirm that cmd.exe is a bit problematic towards pandoc. Powershell works as intended.

Comment: I'll be OK with powershell. Thanks for your help Volkan.

Comment: @user12402799 Glad to help!