# Converting multiple Markdown files to a book-style PDF

Tags: markdown, documentation, pandoc

I have multiple markdown files saved in my repository (Git). These files are used with the Docusaurus engine to generate a static website. The output order of these files is defined in the Docusaurus configuration file. Is there a way in the same way to generate a PDF document? For example, in the configuration file specify the order of markdown files. I've searched for the Pandoc, but it only excepts a directory of markdown files. Are there simple tools that read such configuration file and generate a PDF document?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60805340/2425163

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried https://github.com/TheFern2/markdown-book?

It uses Pandoc with a Python script.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a master Rmd that includes each of them (even generate that list dynamically) and then knit the master.  Check out the "child" chunk option.