# Pandoc: combining different docx file into one using cmd

Tags: markdown, docx, pandoc

I am relatively inexperienced with Pandoc and just ran into a problem. How do convert several markdown files to docx and combine them into one large file using only the Windows Terminal. Also, one markdown file is in a parent folder. This looks like this:
folder A:

```
 img
 docs
 README.md
```

in the folder docs:

```
file1.md
file2.md
file3.md
```

For example, the README, file1 - 3 are to be converted and merged here. In addition, the README file also has links to File1, File2 and File3. How can these references also be converted?

I tried the command

```
pandoc --extract-media ./img input_file.md -o output_file.md
```

Comment: Can you give an example for “the README file also has links to File1, ...”? How do those links look like?

Comment: The Link looks like the following:
```
#Lorem ipsum dolor

##1. [lorem ipsum dolor](docs/file1.md)
```

Comment: You might be able to use the approaches mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/brRs7OX5cMY/m/oviMMSCZAwAJ) and [here](https://groups.google.com/g/pandoc-discuss/c/i8ppLiELYdg/m/pe16RiNhAwAJ). Do those sound like what you have in mind?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60771330/2425163

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, but is there a way to do it in the cmd.exe?