# Powershell Pandoc Batch Processing Current Directory

Tags: powershell, docx, pandoc

I have scoured countless threads such as this [Mac Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10323317/batch-processing-pandoc-conversions) and this seemingly relevant [Powershell Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17157638/batch-processing-pandoc-conversions-in-windows) to no avail. Currently, I am attempting to run

```
for (/r "." %i in (*.docx) do pandoc -o "%~i.md" "%~i")
```

to convert all .docx to .md within the current directory. Unfortunately when running this from the Powershell ISE I am met with the following message

```
Missing statement body in for loop.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingLoopStatement
```

Please advise on how to convert a directory full of .docx files to .md using powershell. I have around 250 docs I would like to convert and am in desperate need of assistance!

Comment: This is not a powershell command, this is a Windows CMD command

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I am not familiar with windows batch or PowerShell scripting and wasn't able to spot the apparently obvious difference :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Shamus Berube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11035186/shamus-berube) points out, your command uses (broken) `cmd.exe` syntax, not PowerShell syntax.

The PowerShell translation is:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.docx | ForEach-Object {
  pandoc -o ($_.FullName + '.md') $_.FullName
}
```